# Cloudwatch does not trigger alarm (empty graph)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, cloudwatch-alarms

I am having the following problem:
I am using a SuccessfulRequestLatency Metric to check if my dynamoDB request takes more than 50ms (p90 > 50ms). To test I used a very low threshold of 5ms. When on alarm, I want to be notified on Slack (Another Alarm I configured for the 5xx worked fine). But I don't get notified. I am using the metric SuccessfulRequestLatency to get / update / put data (using DynamoDB). In the section Cloudwatch > Metrics > Graphed Metrics I can see the graph and how many ms the requests to the DB need. Though in the Alarm I cannot see (empty graph). Does anyone know what the error could be? This is my .yaml file on the Alarm:

```
  DynamoDBCMSPageLatencyTooHighAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmActions:
        - !Ref ErrorNotifier
      AlarmDescription: Alarm if p90 > 50 ms in DynamoDB (GetItem in CMSPage)
      AlarmName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-dynamoDB-CMSPage-latency-too-high
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Dimensions:
        - Name: TableName
          Value: !Ref CmsPageTable
      EvaluationPeriods: 3
      MetricName: SuccessfulRequestLatency
      Namespace: AWS/DynamoDB
      Period: 300
      TreatMissingData: notBreaching
      ExtendedStatistic: p90
      Threshold: 5
```

Thank you all in advance. (images below)
[image: Results in the Metrics]

`[image: Alarm Graph]

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not publish percentile metrics, even though CloudWatch has the option. For that reason you are not seeing an alarm as it's not a valid statistic. You can see valid statistics here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html